# svg styling g element with stroke property

Tags: javascript, css, svg, stroke

Starting for example from this situation:

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="green" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px">
       <rect width="180" height="122.85714" x="211.42857" y="335.21936" />
       <rect width="211.42857" height="182.85715" x="124.28571" y="375.21933" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Thanks to "g" properties, the stroke attribute is inherited by the two "rect" elements.

This is useful for me when the two "rect" elements are not overlapped.

Is there a technique to obtain a unique outline (unique border) when the two "rect" elements are overlapped?

Comment: No...these are different elements each with their own stroke. You'd need to combined them into a single element.

Answer (score 0):

A few lines of [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/) to give the overlapped Rect a different attribute. No shortcut.

```js
var s = Snap('#mySVG');

var g = s.select('#square_group');

var boxA = g.rect(11,11,200,200);
var boxB = g.rect(50,50,180,180);

if (Snap.path.isBBoxIntersect(boxA.getBBox(), boxB.getBBox())) {
    boxB.attr({
    fill: "#bada55",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 5
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>


<svg id="mySVG" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="square_group" fill="green" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px">
    </g>
  </svg>
```